# webdriver : can't get the broken links

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

So I can get url with

```
driver.get('https://www.w3.org/')
```

But what I want to test is, if I give a fault link, I should get something like

```
This page does not exist.
```

But when I try to capture this, I can't get the result

This is failed, can't report the fault link

```
link = "https://www.w3.org/fault_link"

if driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'This page does not exist')]"):
    logger.info("Found fault link %s", link)
```

this is failed as well, can't capture it.

```
element = driver.find_element(
                    By.XPATH, '//*[@id="__next"]/div[1]/main')

# when I print out the element text, I can see the output
# 404 ERROR
# This page does not exist.
# The page you are looking for could not be found.
# Go back home →
logger.info(element.text)

if e.text=='This page does not exist.':
     logger.info("Found fault link %s", link)
```

this is failed as well

```
if search("This page does not exist.", element.text):
    logger.info("Found fault link %s", link)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Normally I use selenium only to collect the links (collecting hrefs for all anchors). After that I use different library to check the links for being broken. Sending http get request to the url. You can create some sort of check which say is status code is >= 400 you can consider the link to be broken. I am not talking about malformed links because this is totally different story.                                                                            import requests

x = requests.get('https://google.com')
print(x.status_code)

Comment: any sample codes for sharing and reference?

Comment: I will share as answer

Answer (score 1):

Your test is failing since you expecting to find non-existing text.
This text `This page does not exist` in **not** presented on `https://www.w3.org/fault_link` page.
What you should look for on that specific page is `Document not found` text.
So, this code is working for that specific page:

```py
url = "https://www.w3.org/fault_link"
driver.get(url)

if driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*[contains(text(), 'Document not found')]"):
    print("Found fault link %s", url)
```

The output is:

```
Found fault link %s https://www.w3.org/fault_link
```

Generally you should understand that each web site will present different error / notification for non-existing page.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to do something like this. Have in mind that I dont program in python, just did a quick search in order to assemble the example:

```
import requests 
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
assert "Python" in driver.title
elements = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//a")
print(len(elements))
links = [elem.get_attribute('href') for elem in elements]
print(links)
x = requests.get(links[0]) 
print(x.status_code)
```

I am checking the status code only of the first link found on the page. You can do foreach and if something has status code >= 400 then we are talking about broken link.